# How do I prevent SOLineSplit and INItemPlan from deleting when Qty = 0?

Tags: acumatica

I noticed that when the quantity of a SOLine is zero, there are no SOLineSplit or INItemPlan records available for that line. The second the quantity is greater than 0, the system makes those records, and if the qty is set back to 0, the records are deleted.

Is there a way to prevent the SOLineSplit and INItemPlan objects from deleting when a record is set to 0 quantity?

Is there a way to still have the system create an SOLineSplit and INItemPlan if the SOLine is initially created with a 0 quantity?

The reason for the question is that a customer wants the system to lock the SOLine after a certain point, but also allow for the Qty to be adjusted from another screen. Since this is not directly changing the value on the SOLine screen, this isn't triggering the events to create the split and plan.

I have tried creating an instance of SOOrderEntry in the custom screen as follows:

```
SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

//Also tried graph.Transactions.Current = line, but did not work
graph.Transactions.Update(line);

graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Doing that keeps resulting in a null object reference error:

> Error: An error occurred during processing of the field OrderQty : Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>      at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.SOLine_OrderQty_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e) ...

Comment: Microsoft SQL server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with your statement in using `SOOrderEntry` is you are not truly loading the order in the graph to update it correctly. After you create the graph instance and before the transaction update, you should load the document header like this...

```
SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();

graph.Document.Current = graph.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>(line.OrderNbr, line.OrderType); 

if(graph.Document.Current == null)
{
    return;
}

graph.Transactions.Update(line);

graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

As for controlling how the plan and split records are entered from SOOrderEntry... The entries are controlled through the attributes on PlanID. The cache attached is where this gets added on SOOrderEntry...

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Append)]
[SOLineSplitPlanID(typeof(SOOrder.noteID), typeof(SOOrder.hold), typeof(SOOrder.orderDate))]
protected virtual void SOLineSplit_PlanID_CacheAttached(PXCache sender)
{
}
```

You can make your own graph extension of Sales order and replace the attribute with your own version of SOLineSplitPlanID... it might be a battle for you as I am not sure why you would want the plan record to exist when zero qty to plan.

Comment: I'm going to try your first solution. I'd rather not mess with how Acumatica fundamentally works in that fashion as I am sure there is a purpose for it. If it would be possible for me to have the split and plan create when the user adjusts the value from zero to anything greater than zero, that would be perfect.

Comment: i thought the issue was that the split/plan record DOES create when the user changes the value from zero? If you use the SOOrderEntry graph as i have it shown it should take care of this for you?

Comment: Wow, I kinda facepalmed on this one. I realized I didn't set the header record after I started examining what you wrote. Whoops... Thanks again Brendan!

Comment: no problem. Glad that worked for you. Thanks for confirming.